# How should ESAPI executeSystemCommand sanitise the file path properly to satisfy Veracode check?

Tags: veracode, esapi

I invoke the external command within my Java app with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` or `ProcessBuilder`. Works fine but Veracode complains on it with [CWE-78](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/78.html). I'm trying to use `ESAPI` wrapper to sanitise the input and path the check.

The arfifact is the latest

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

`ESAPI.properties` are

```
ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.logging.slf4j.Slf4JLogFactory
Logger.LogEncodingRequired=false
Logger.UserInfo=false
Logger.ClientInfo=false
Logger.LogApplicationName=false
Logger.ApplicationName=my-app
Logger.LogServerIP=false
IntrusionDetector.Disable=true
Executor.ApprovedExecutables=/usr/bin/less
```

The code is:

```
@Test
void esapiTest() throws ExecutorException {
    Executor executor = DefaultExecutor.getInstance();
    ExecuteResult executeResult = executor.executeSystemCommand(
            new File("/usr/bin/less"),
            new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList("/etc/hosts"))
    );
    System.out.println("out = " + executeResult.getOutput());
    System.out.println("err = " + executeResult.getErrors());
}
```

The output is

```
out = 
err = \/etc\/hosts: No such file or directory
```

As far as I got the issue is that ESAPI's `UnixCodec` sanitises all non-alpha character with the backslash. This is fine for the `shell` i.e.

```
/usr/bin/less \/etc\/hosts
```

but not for the `ProcessBuilder` that is under the hood.

What am I doing wrong? How to invoke the command?

Answer (score 0):

I think your main "problem" is misunderstanding that the ESAPI Codecs that are used with the `DefaultExecutor` class are assuming that any "OS command injection" is being interpreted via a "command line interpreter", i.e., a "shell". You are not invoking a shell here. If you were, the shell would remove the (in this case) backslash escaped argument from your path for "/etc/hosts". So if this were written as (say) the command:

```
/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/less /etc/hosts
```

it would [sort of] work (except if you tried running it over HTTP, the input to 'less' my be hosed; but "/bin/cat" ought to work fine).

Instead, try writing your test something like this:

```
@Test
void esapiTest() throws ExecutorException {
    Executor executor = ESAPI.executor();
    File binSh = new File("/bin/sh").getCanonicalFile();
    List params = new ArrayList();
    params.add("-c");
        //Use '/bin/cat' because 'less' may be troublesome
    params.add("\"" + "/bin/cat" + "/etc/hosts" + "\"");
    ExecuteResult executeResult = executor.executeSystemCommand(binSh, params);
    System.out.println("out = " + executeResult.getOutput());
    System.out.println("err = " + executeResult.getErrors());
}
```

Note 1: If you I'm not sure how  user-friendly `ProcessBuilder` is with commands that eventually try to do **`ioctl`** system calls to set the tty device in 'raw' mode, like commands such as "vim" or "less", which is why I changed your "/usr/bin/less" to "/bin/cat". YMMV.

Note 2: In your **ESAPI.properties** file, you'd have to make sure that the property '**Executor.ApprovedExecutables**' is set to whatever the canonical name of "/bin/sh" is on your system. E.g., on my system, "/bin/sh" is a symbolic link to "/bin/dash", so you would have to include something like

```
Executor.ApprovedExecutables=/bin/bash,/bin/dash
```

(or at least "/bin/dash") should work.

Comment: `params.add("\"" + "/bin/cat" + "/etc/hosts" + "\"");` I guess the space after `cat` is missed, but anyhow it doesn't working for me saying `err = /bin/sh: "/bin/cat /etc/hosts": No such file or directory`. ESAPI.propeties are adjusted, /bin/sh and /bin/cat are not symbolic links (macOS Monterey)